# list articles for each category in a view in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

i have two tables `Category` and `Articles`. i want to list articles of each category in articles `index.ctp` in cakephp3. i have used two query in my controller, one to list category and the other to list articles for each category. this is the two tables content:

```
|--------------------|----------------------|
|  Category          |  Articles            |
|--------------------|----------------------|
| idCategory         | idArticles           |
| Reference          | Title                |
|                    | Description          |
|                    | Created              |
|                    | Category.idCategory  |
|--------------------|----------------------|
```

below is my code in `articlesController.php`

```php
$category = $this->paginate(TableRegistry::get('Category')->find('all'));
$this->set(compact('category'));

$article = $this->Articles
    ->find('all',array( 'order' => array('Created DESC')))
    ->contain(['Category'])
    ->where(['Category.idCategory' == 'idCategory']);
```

in my `index.ctp` template i have used two foreach loop:

```php
foreach($category as $c) {
    h($c->reference)

    foreach ($article as $a) {
        h($a->title)
    }
}
```

but when i display, all articles appear in the first category and the others category are empty while articles have differents `Category_idCategory`.
Something wrong in my request ?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are wrong. You've got a single list of all categories, and then a single list of all articles. And `->where(['Category.idCategory' == 'idCategory'])` is using PHP comparison operator, so this parses to `->where([false])`, surely not what you want.

You've got `contain` used in there in your article query, but it should actually be in the category query, and then no article query at all:

```
$categories = $this->paginate(TableRegistry::get('Category')->find('all')->contain(['Article']);
```

Also, Cake standards would be to use `Categories` and `Articles` as table names here; is there a reason that you're not following that? Doing so will make your life easier in general.

Your index would then be something like this:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    h($category->reference);

    foreach ($category->article as $article) {
        h($article->title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very muck Greg Schmidt. It works fine now